# Is there any number that satisfies $\lvert n\rvert > 2, n\in\Bbb{C}$ and $a^n+b^n=c^n$ where $a,b,c \in \Bbb{C}$

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

Fermat's Last Theorem has been proven, and this means that there are no integer values of $n$ that satisfy the equation $a^n+b^n=c^n$ where $a,b,c \in \Bbb{C}$ for $n>2$. But are there any rational values of $n$ with solutions? Any real values? Complex values? Has 2 been proven to be the largest $n$ with solutions?

Comment: Your statement of Fermat's theorem is wrong. $a,b,c$ should be positive integers.

Comment: It may be of interest that $\sqrt 2+\sqrt 8=\sqrt{18}$.

Comment: $\sqrt a +\sqrt a =\sqrt {4a}$

Comment: I specified values greater than 2

Comment: Yes but now let $a=z^5$

Answer (score 0):

Fermat's Last Theorem rules out rational values for $n \gt 2$, because you can clear the fractions and get an integral solution.  In the reals there are solutions for all $n$.  For example $3^4+4^4=337=(\sqrt[4]{337})^4$